# when clicked on mobile devices spritesheet images display grey box around itself

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I created a spritesheet; on desktop's everything is okay. However, i then tried to view it on my iphone 5s it's displaying okay, but when clicked on the image a dark grey box momentarily appears. I instantly thought maybe i have conflicting CSS, but on further research found that this happens when i try to click on any sprite image:

example site: 
http://css-tricks.com/examples/FadeImageWithSprite/

when any of the buttons are clicked prior to them changing color grey box appears. Hope someone can help me out

Answer (score 0):

The grey box is the notification of touch-click event similar to pseudo ::active.

you can change the color by adding this css properties to buttons, a, class, id or tag.

example for 0.3 opacity for black or 0 opacity to make it invisible.

```
body{
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```